# Azure Function Host: worker process was unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am at loss. Have a durable function that worked perfectly for a while then suddenly getting Script Host error and function just shuts down.

After turning all logging on I am still unable to understand what is going on. The only meaningful message is:

```
HTTP Error 503.0 - Service Unavailable

The service is unavailable.



Most likely causes:
•An invalid identity in the application pool could cause this error.
•The application pool is no longer running because of configuration or reaching application failure limits.
•The concurrent application request limit was reached.
```

Host.json

```
  {
  "durableTask": {
    "HubName": "ADFParallelHubV1"
  }
}
```

App Service Plan: Standard S1 Large

[image: references]
[image: IIS Error]

UPDATE:
I have downgraded Function.SDK from 1.0.13 to 1.0.11 and now I get different IIS error (see below):
[image: IIS Error 503]

Comment: Please see https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94 which should get you going.

Comment: 503 error is simply shows that your service is inaccessible / stopped/too busy. You could try to retry the URL from the address bar again.You could refer to this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/503-service-unavailable-explained-2622940). If you use the free or shared price tiers,I suggest you could scale your App Service Plan up  to get more instances(like Basic/Standard) to avoid resource limits.

Comment: @PetarVučetin That update seems to have taken out a lot of folks. That 503 error page is generic (and generally misleading). Open the Kudu page from the portal and download the diagnostics zip (I think it's on the Kudu Tools menu). In there you can find detailed logs that should show you the real error from the Functions webjob host. (Edit: I see you already downloaded it; the html error pages aren't useful, check for other error logs -- sometimes you have to let it spin a minute or two before the log files get updated.)

Comment: @DavidEbbo can you make it an answer in case it helps someone?

Comment: @McGuireV10 thanks for the tip.

Comment: @PetarVučetin ok, added an Answer.

Comment: @PetarVučetin see also the discussion [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/745) if you need to figure out how to debug locally. Right now the VSIX is out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by the recent breaking changes to the Functions v2 Preview runtime. For info and ways to move forward can be found on https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94.

In this specific case, you likely just need to update the Durable package reference and republish.